# What order to apply SharePoint 2010 Enterprise SP1 and June 2011 CU?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, service-pack, patching

It's September 2011.  We just installed SharePoint 2010 Enterprise RTM.  Want to install SharePoint 2010 SP1. Do we need to install SharePoint Foundation SP1 first? And should we install June update even though SP1 we are pulling is from late June 2011?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! Please don't add your name or "Thanks" as a signature to posts as this doesn't provide valuable information. Your user name is already displayed on the post, and the best way to show thanks is by upvoting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The guidance and "best practice" up until the August 2011 CU is to install SPF Service Packs and CU's on Server edition. From August 2011 the packaging process has changed and you only need one package to install.

So in order to install SP1 + June CU do this: (the Microsoft recommendation is to install June CU directly after SP1, there are a couple of nasty regressions in SP1 that you probably don't want)

- SPF SP1
- SPF June 2011 CU
- SPS SP1
- SPS June 2011 CU
- *Reboot*
- *Make sure you've applied the patches on all machines before proceeding*
- Run PSConfig

In order to install SP1 + Aug CU do this:

- SPF SP1
- SPS SP1
- SPS Aug 2011 CU
- *Reboot*
- *Make sure you've applied the patches on all machines before proceeding*
- Run PSConfig

Better be safe than sorry...

Comment: Should we reboot between steps? It's asking me to.. but I'd rather not. I know to cancel out of config wizard until all servers are done. Thanks.

Comment: You only need ro reboot once