# SharePoint 2010 SP1 from 6/24 KB2460045 - does it include Foundation sp1, SharePoint sp1 and Cumulative from june already?

Tags: installation, patching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What order to apply SharePoint 2010 Enterprise SP1 and June 2011 CU?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19374/what-order-to-apply-sharepoint-2010-enterprise-sp1-and-june-2011-cu)

Confused... If we just installed SharePoint 2010 Enterprise RTM and want to patch up to SP1.  Do we need to install Foundation SP1, SharePoint SP1 and June cumulative  or just this SP1 from late June? Not sure if just finding old information online prior to this.

officeserver2010sp1-kb2460045-x64-fullfile-en-us.exe   6/24/2011 ?

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26623

Thanks.

---

Comment: I did not even know that existed.. how cool is that... lol can it be easily moved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - The new and right way is.

Foundation Server SP1

Foundation LanguagePack SP1

Foundation CU June refresh

then

SharePoint 2010 SP1

SharePoint 2010 LanguagePack SP1

SharePoint 2010 CU June refresh

After that run Configuration Wizard first on CA then on WFE

/Rasmus